# Swing confusion about firstIndex and lastIndex

Tags: java, swing, listselectionlistener

I am learning to use lists in Java Swing. While writing a small program to understand the working of `ListSelectionModel` and `ListSelectionEvent` using `JList`, I got confused regarding the values given by `getFirstIndex` and `getLastIndex`.

The documentation for each says -

`getFirstIndex` :

> Returns the index of the first row whose selection may have changed.

and `getLastIndex`

> Returns the index of the last row whose selection may have changed.

Now lets say I have a list like this(with single range selections allowed) -

```
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
Element 4
Element 5
```

Initially, none are selected.Now, I selected 1 and firstIndex gave 0, lastIndex gave 0 which is correct.

Now, I hold down shift and selected 3. Here, firstIndex gave 0 and lastIndex gave 2. lastIndex is fine, but I have a few questions regarding the value of firstIndex -

1. Element 1 is still selected and its selection has not changed, then how is firstIndex 0 ?
2. Keeping in view the above point, shouldn't firstIndex be 1, since that is the first row whose selection has changed (unselected -> selected) ?

Also, the list shows elements as selected by a different background. Now when I make a selection, it also shows that element with a border ? What does that indicate ?

Answer (score 2):

If you select `Element 1` and then hold down the shift key and select `Element 3` you have a range selection from `Element 1` to `Element 3`. The `JList` should render the blue background (default selection indicator) for `Element 1`, `Element 2` and `Element 3`.

Thus the `ListSelectionEvent` correctly reports that the current selection is from index 0 to index 2.
These index range represents the elements in your `ListModel`.

The `ListSelectionModel` as well as the `ListSelectionEvent` report the current selection and not selection changes from a previous selection to the current.

Comment: Okay. But, lets say I keep this selection. Now, keeping Shift pressed, I select Element 4. Then firstIndex return 2 and lastIndex 3. Shouldnt it be 0-3 ?

Comment: I cant't reproduce the problem. If I select the first list element, hold down the shift key and select the third list element. Then 1 2 3 are selected. If I keep holding the shift key and select 4. than 1 2 3 4 are selected. I tried it with this sample app http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html

Comment: No, you misunderstand me. What I'm saying is that the selections are fine - I see 1,2,3,4 selected. But firstIndex returns 2 and lastIndex 3, and not 0 and 3.